# How can I save data from background.js to local machine and fetch this data when required by a button on the popup.html page?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, popup

I just wanted to save my background.js data to my local machine and fetch the data to my extension whenever there happens to be a  click on some popup.html button. Is there any way to do so and Is it different for different operating systems ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All Chrome's extensions APIs are cross-platform. Regarding the storage, remember that content scripts run in the context of webpages, not extension pages. So when you access the localStorage from your contentscript, you are retrieving the storage from that particular page not the extension's storage.

Try this:

**popup.js**

```
document.getElementById("myButton").addEventListener("click", function(){
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({action: "getStorage", key: "name"}, function(response) {
     alert(value.data);
  });
});
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.action === "getStorage") {
      sendResponse({value: localStorage[request.key]});
    }
});
```

Comment: this is overkill. chrome has better ways than localstorage.